# Opera border-radius not hiding corners of background

Tags: background, opera, css

I created a box `#text` with a class `.text_bg` at its top, as you can see [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVGBQ/1/).

Within Firefox, Chrome and IE it's displayed fine as you can see in that jsfiddle, but in Opera the rounded corners of the box do not clipse the background.

How can I fix this?
Similar topics for this issue suggested background-clip and background-origin, but neither seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you're doing it the way you are, with the extra div. Just set the background to repeat-x, aligned to the top of the div. I can't save to jsfiddle to show you the example, so here's the updated code.

**Updated HTML:**

```
<div id="text" class="text_bg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p> 
</div>
```

**Updated CSS:**

```
#text {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 328px;
    margin-top: 110px;
    background-color: rgba(40,40,40,0.7);
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top:0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -ms-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -o-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    margin-left: 110px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -ms-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,1.0);    
    overflow:hidden;
}    

.text_bg {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,102,204,1),rgba(0,153,255,1));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,102,204,1),rgba(0,153,255,1));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(0,102,204,1),rgba(0,153,255,1));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0,102,204,1),rgba(0,153,255,1));
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,102,204,1),rgba(0,153,255,1));
    background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiIHByZXNlcnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89Im5vbmUiPgo8bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9ImczOTEiIGdyYWRpZW50VW5pdHM9InVzZXJTcGFjZU9uVXNlIiB4MT0iMCUiIHkxPSIwJSIgeDI9IjAlIiB5Mj0iMTAwJSI+CjxzdG9wIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMwMDY2Q0MiIG9mZnNldD0iMCIvPjxzdG9wIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMwMDk5RkYiIG9mZnNldD0iMSIvPgo8L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50Pgo8cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2czOTEpIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=);
    background-size: auto 54px;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:top;
    height: 54px;
    width: 120%;
    margin-left:-10%;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom:-25px;
    border-radius:8px;
}
```

Comment: Just a clarification: Opera implemented border-radius without the prefix, so -o-border-radius isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks, now the problem with the eclipsing corners has been solved :). But now there's a different problem: whenever I scroll down my site, the background in that textbox seems to be fixed NOT to the textbox but rather somewhere else, so it doesn't scroll with the textbox up and down. This only happens in Opera.

Comment: Have a link to the full page so we can see that?

Comment: I finally solved the problem by listing the background SVG image I need for IE (as it does not support linear gradients yet) at the first place of the CSS rule (before the -o-linear-gradient instead of having it behind the -o-linear-gradient).